# Cumulative Durational Builds in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames. `df1` contains build factors and `df2` contains dollars accumulated through different lengths of maturity:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dur': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'build': [35, .96, .25, .10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dur': [1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4],
                    'out': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                    'ytd_dol': [110, 3600, 6302, 1300, 3450, 1550]})
print(df1)
#   dur  build
#0    1  35.00
#1    2   0.96
#2    3   0.25
#3    4   0.10

print(df2)
#   dur  out  ytd_dol
#0    1    1      110
#1    3    1     3600
#2    4    1     6302
#3    3    2     1300
#4    4    2     3450
#5    4    3     1550
```

What I am trying to is project the new `ytd_dol` value in `df2` at each `dur` and `out` combination, using the values from `df1`. The manual calculations to complete this for each row are as follows:

- Row 0: `110 + (110 * 35)`
- Row 1: `3600 + (3600 * .25)`
- Row 2: `6302 + (6302 * .10)`
- Row 3: `1300 + (1300 * .96) + (1300 * .96 * .25)`
- Row 4: `3450 + (3450 * .25) + (3450 * .25 * .10)`
- Row 5: `1550 + (1550 * .96) + (1550 * .96 *.25) + (1550 * .96 * .25 * .10)`

Using the equations above, `df2` would be updated with a new column and look like this:

```
print(df2)
#   dur  out  ytd_dol  proj_ytd_dol
#0    1    1      110       3960.00
#1    3    1     3600       4500.00
#2    4    1     6302       6932.20
#3    3    2     1300       2860.00
#4    4    2     3450       4398.75
#5    4    3     1550       3447.20
```

Comment: what is the relevance of 35.00 in the first row of df1? will there be only 4 rows ?

Comment: @moys it was just noise to the MWE. I updated the question so that it is now incorporated in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally** understood your logic.

Code below should give the output you want.

```
result = np.select([df2['out']==1, 
                    df2['out']==2,
                    df2['out']==3], 
                   [df2['ytd_dol'] \
                    + df2['ytd_dol'] \
                       .mul(df2['dur'].map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])), 
                    df2['ytd_dol']
                    + df2['ytd_dol'] \
                       .mul((df2['dur']-1).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])) \
                    + df2['ytd_dol'] \
                       .mul((df2['dur']-1).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])) \
                       .mul((df2['dur']).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])),
                    df2['ytd_dol'] \
                    + df2['ytd_dol'] \
                       .mul((df2['dur']-2).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])) \
                    + df2['ytd_dol'] \
                       .mul((df2['dur']-2).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])) \
                       .mul((df2['dur']-1).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])) \
                    + df2['ytd_dol'] \
                       .mul((df2['dur']-2).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])) \
                       .mul((df2['dur']-1).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build'])) \
                       .mul((df2['dur']).map(df1.set_index('dur')['build']))])

df2['proj_ytd_dol'] = result
```

**Output**

```
print(df2)
#   dur  out  ytd_dol  proj_ytd_dol
#0    1    1      110       3960.00
#1    3    1     3600       4500.00
#2    4    1     6302       6932.20
#3    3    2     1300       2860.00
#4    4    2     3450       4398.75
#5    4    3     1550       3447.20
```

Comment: even when formatted for legibility, still more concise than my answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I came up with on my own, that gets me what I want, but I feel that it could definitely be simplified. What I'm doing is looping through each record in `df2` and applying a custom rule to it, depending on the record's `out` value.

```
proj_ytd_dol = []
for i in range(0, df2.shape[0]):
    r = df2.iloc[i:i+1]

    if r['out'].iloc[0] == 1:
        focal_dur = r['dur'].iloc[0]
        df1a = df1[df1['dur'] == focal_dur]
        proj_ytd = r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                   + (r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[0])

    if r['out'].iloc[0] == 2:
        focal_durs = [(r['dur'].iloc[0] - 1), r['dur'].iloc[0]]
        df1a = df1[df1['dur'].isin(focal_durs)]
        proj_ytd = r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                   + (r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[0]) \
                   + (r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[1])

    if r['out'].iloc[0] == 3:
        focal_durs = [(r['dur'].iloc[0] - 2), 
                      (r['dur'].iloc[0] - 1), 
                      r['dur'].iloc[0]]
        df1a = df1[df1['dur'].isin(focal_durs)]
        proj_ytd = r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                   + (r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[0]) \
                   + (r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[1]) \
                   + (r['ytd_dol'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[0] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[1] \
                      * df1a['build'].iloc[2])

    proj_ytd_dol.append(proj_ytd)

df2['proj_ytd_dol'] = proj_ytd_dol

print(df2)
#   dur  out  ytd_dol  proj_ytd_dol
#0    1    1      110       3960.00
#1    3    1     3600       4500.00
#2    4    1     6302       6932.20
#3    3    2     1300       2860.00
#4    4    2     3450       4398.75
#5    4    3     1550       3447.20
```